# Combine two SQL lite databases with Python

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, merge

I have the following code in python to update db where the first column is "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE:

```
con = lite.connect('test_score.db')
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO scores VALUES (NULL,?,?,?)", (first,last,score))
    item = cur.fetchone()
    on.commit()
    cur.close()
    con.close()
```

I get table "scores" with following data:

```
1,Adam,Smith,68
2,John,Snow,76
3,Jim,Green,88
```

Two different users (userA and userB) copy test_score.db and code to their computer and use it separately.
I get back two db test_score.db but now with different content:

user A test_score.db :

```
1,Adam,Smith,68
2,John,Snow,76
3,Jim,Green,88
4,Jim,Green,91
5,Tom,Hanks,15
```

user A test_score.db :

```
1,Adam,Smith,68
2,John,Snow,76
3,Jim,Green,88
4,Chris,Prat,99
5,Tom,Hanks,09
6,Tom,Hanks,15
```

I was trying to use

```
insert into AuditRecords select * from toMerge.AuditRecords;
```

to combine two db into one but failed as the first column is a unique id. Two db have now the same ids but with different or the same data and merging is failing.
I would like to find unique rows in both db (all values different ignoring id) and merge results to one full db.

Result should be something like this:

```
1,Adam,Smith,68
2,John,Snow,76
3,Jim,Green,88
4,Jim,Green,91
5,Tom,Hanks,15
6,Chris,Prat,99
7,Tom,Hanks,09
```

I can extract each value one by one and compare but want to avoid it as I might have longer rows in the future with more columns.

Sorry if it is obvious and easy questions, I'm still learning. I tried to find the answer but failed, please point me to answer if it already exists somewhere else. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the approach to resolve duplicated rows. Will consider the max score? The min? The first one?

Considering the table `AuditRecords` has all the lines of both User A and B, you can use GROUP BY to deduplicate rows and use an aggregation function to resolve the score:

```sql
insert into
    AuditRecords
select
    id,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    max(score) as score
from
    toMerge.AuditRecords
group by
    id,
    first_name,
    last_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement you should have defined a `UNIQUE` constraint for the combination of the columns `first`, `last` and `score`:

```
CREATE TABLE AuditRecords(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  first TEXT,
  last TEXT,
  score INTEGER,
  UNIQUE(first, last, score)
);
```

Now you can use [`INSERT OR IGNORE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) to merge the tables:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO AuditRecords(first, last, score) 
SELECT first, last, score 
FROM toMerge.AuditRecords;
```

Note that you must explicitly define the list of the columns that will receive the values and in this list the `id` is missing because its value will be autoincremented by each insertion.

Another way to do it without defining the `UNIQUE` constraint is to use [`EXCEPT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound_select_statements):

```
INSERT INTO AuditRecords(first, last, score) 
SELECT first, last, score FROM toMerge.AuditRecords
EXCEPT
SELECT first, last, score FROM AuditRecords
```